# Show that series $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{a_n}}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, radicals, nested-radicals

Let $a_1$ = $\sqrt{2}$ and  $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{a_n}}$ for all natural numbers n.
Show that the sequence $a_n$ converges

I've been doing problems which use the Root/Ratio test. I don't see how I can use that here.
I started with $\sqrt2$ < $2$, and $\sqrt{a_1}$ < $1$ and tried to reason out the series. That doesn't work. How would I show that it converges to some value $L$?

Comment: You seem to be confusing *sequence* and *series*. (The title says "series," but you mean sequence. On the other hand, the root/ratio tests apply only to series!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence is monotone increasing. Show that it is bounded from above and you are done.

**Monotonicity.** Proof by induction. We have $$a_1 - a_0 = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}} - \sqrt{2} \approx 0.134 > 0$$ Hence assume the sequence is monotone increasing for $n > 0$. We have $$a_{n + 1} - a_n = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_n}} - \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_{n-1}}} = \frac{\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a_{n-1}}}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_n}} + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_{n-1}}}} = \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{\left( \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_n}} + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_{n-1}}}\right)\left( \sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{a_{n-1}}\right)} > 0$$ since by the induction hypothesis $a_n - a_{n-1} > 0$ and the sequence is for sure positive (one can show by induction, that the sequence is bounded below by $1$).

**Boundedness.** The sequence is bounded above by $2$ (this is not sharp, but its an upper bound). Obviously, $\sqrt{2} \leqslant 2$. Assume, $a_n \leqslant 2$. Then $$a_{n + 1} = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_n}} \leqslant \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}} \leqslant \sqrt{4} = 2$$ since the root function is monotone increasing and of course $\sqrt{2} \leqslant 3$.

Hence we can conclude, that the sequence converges.

**Limit.** If you want to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ we stick to the following trick. Denote the limit by $L$. Then it must hold $$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{a_n}} = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{L}}$$ since the root function is continuous. Hence we have to solve $$L = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{L}}$$ or equivalently $$L^4 - 2L^2 - L + 1 = 0$$ However this is not so easy to solve. Perhaps, someone has a good idea to solve this, but using Wolfram, we get the two roots $$L_1 \approx 0.524829 \qquad L_2 \approx 1.4902$$ So for sure $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq L_1$$ since the sequence is monotone increasing and bounded below by $1$. Thus $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L_2 \approx 1.4902 $$

Comment: How do you show it's monotone increasing, though? That's a quite important part.

Comment: @ClementC. Just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}$ on $\{x>0\}$, $f'(x)={1\over 4}{1\over \sqrt{1+\sqrt x}}{1\over\sqrt x}>0$ thus $f$ is an increasing function. Since $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ and $f(a_1)\geq a_1$, we deduce recursively that $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence.

Now let $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$, write $b_1=\sqrt2$ and $b_{n+1}=g(b_n)$. Remark that $g'(x)={1\over 2}{1\over\sqrt{1+x}}>0$. Since $g(a_1)>a_1$. We deduce that $(b_n)$ is an increasing sequence.

Remark that $f(x)\leq g(x)$ if $x>1$. Suppose that $1\leq a_n\leq b_n$, $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)\leq g(a_n)\leq g(b_n)=b_{n+1}$. Since $a_1=b_1$, we deduce that for every integer $n$, $a_n\leq b_n$.

$g(x)=x$ i.e $\sqrt{1+x}=x$ i.e $x^2-x-1=0$. The positive root of this equation is ${{1+\sqrt5}\over 2}>\sqrt2$. Suppose that $a_n\leq b_n\leq {{1+\sqrt5}\over 2}$, $a_{n+1}\leq b_{n+1}=g(b_n)\leq g({{1+\sqrt5}\over 2})={{1+\sqrt5}\over 2}$. Since $a_1=b_1\leq {{1+\sqrt5}\over 2}$, we deduce recursively that $(a_n)$ is an increasing bounded sequence thus converges.

Comment: From $f'(X)>0$ you can not prove $f(X) > X$. Say, $f(X)=X-1$.

Comment: And actually, here this crucially depends on the initial condition. If we had had $a_1=3$, say, one can check the sequence would have been *decreasing* instead. (It is only increasing ecause $a_1=\sqrt{2}$ is less than the fixed point of the function, which is roughly $1.49$.)

Comment: who downvote here and why?

Comment: I did, for the reason above. Your argument was (and still is as I write this comment) wrong.

Comment: Why is it wrong, even if $a_1=3, f'>0$.

Comment: We would still have $f'>0$ **but the sequence would be decreasing**. You seem to miss the fact that your justification for why the sequence is increasing is wrong. You cannot deduce it from the mere fact that $f$ is increasing, as the comments above point out.

Comment: But $a_2=f(a_1)>a_1$, use your calculator to verify this. So suppose $a_n<a_{n+1}$, $f(a_n)<f(a_{n+1})$.

Comment: So that relies crucially on the relative order of the first two terms. Which, up until 3mn ago (your last edit, after all the comments above) was never mentioned in your answer. Before that, your argument was wrong, as mentioned above; now, it is OK.